# C++ visual studio, i/o in txt file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Would you please help me with this assignment.

I am supposed to create a txt file that contains ID and mark for three students and the output should be the ID and a message in a different txt file.

When I try running the code, the output txt file is blank.
I tried changing the code so the program outputs results on screen, but for some reason it doesn't read the first line and it repeats the third!

I'm using Visual studio 2012.

input data:

```
20112233    90
20115566    80
20113756    70
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void main ()
{

    int ID, mark, c=1;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open ("marks.txt");
    fin >> ID >> mark;

    ofstream fout;
    fout.open ("grades");

    while (c<=3)
    {   

    fin >> ID >> mark;

    if (mark >= 90 && mark <= 100) {
            fout << ID << "\t" << "Excellent" << endl;
    c++;
    }
    else if (mark >= 80 && mark <= 89) {
            fout << ID << "\t" << "Very Good" << endl;
        c++;
    }

    else if (mark >= 70 && mark <= 79) {
            fout << ID << "\t" << "Good" << endl;
    c++;
    }

        else  if (mark >= 60 && mark <= 69) {
            fout << ID << "\t" << "Accepted" << endl;
        c++;
        }

        else if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 59) {
            fout << ID << "\t" << "Fail" << endl;
        c++;
        }

        else fout << "Wrong data";

    }


    fin.close ();
    fout.close ();

    system ("PAUSE");

}
```

Comment: No first line: you've got a `fin >> ID >> mark;` before you enter the loop and you throw those values away. Duplicate last one: you're attempting to read past the end fo the file and maybe the behaviour of `fin >>` is to leave the current values as-is if there's nothing to read? I don't know the input stream classes. In any case you should throw away `c` and loop until the file stream reports it's empty, not by counting lines. But if you're using VS2012 you've got a great debugger to hand - can't you step through with that and debug this?

Comment: I didn't noticed that I entered fin >> ID >> mark; twice. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through the steps:

1. Open the <kbd>.txt</kbd> file for input:

   ```
   std::ifstream fin("marks.txt");
   ```

   Note how we're using the constructor to open the .txt file instead of using `open`. This is the preferred method of opening .txt files when the path is known at construction.
2. Open the <kbd>.txt</kbd> file for output:

   ```
   std::ofstream fout("grade");
   ```
3. Create the variables whose values are to be extracted from the input txt file. That would be the ID and the grade:

   ```
   int ID, mark;
   ```
4. Now, extracting the values from a txt file is very straightforward. If you want to extract the values for each line present in the txt file, then there's no need to set a counter - when the extraction hits the EOF character (end-of-file) the extraction will cease.

   The idiomatic method for extraction is to perform the extraction with the conditional expression of a loop so it can return the stream so valid file conditions can be assessed. This is done automatically through the formatted and unformatted I/O operators in IOStreams:

   ```
   while (fin >> ID >> mark)
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```
5. Close the file: This is done automatically through the destruction of the stream classes themselves. If you no longer have any use for these files, just let them close themselves when they go out of scope or when the program ends. Meaning don't call `close()`.

Comment: Thank you so much dear! I wonder why we didn't study this way. Very simple and straightforward. :)

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**, the `main` function must return an `int`.

**Secondly**, you seem to perform a read from the stream and throw it away.

```
fin >> ID >> mark; // Read tokens and clear them from the stream.
```

**Thirdly**, you don't check if and what you read from the stream.

```
while (c<=3)
{   

fin >> ID >> mark; // What if this fails?
```

**Try something like this instead:**

```
#include <fstream>

int main () {
    std::ifstream fin("marks.txt");
    std::ofstream fout("grades");

    int id, mark;
    while (fin >> id >> mark) { // Loop while tokens can be read successfully
        if (mark >= 90 && mark <= 100) {
            fout << id << "\tExcellent" << std::endl;
        } else if (mark >= 80 && mark <= 89) {
            fout << id << "\tVery Good" << std::endl;
        } else if (mark >= 70 && mark <= 79) {
            fout << id << "\tGood" << std::endl;
        } /* ... */
    }
}
```